# Is it possible to get past undefined variable using dynamic input fields in PHP?

Tags: php

Got an error of

> Undefined index: mytext

because I've got a form wherein it has a button wherein it adds an input field dynamically!
But what if I will not add an input field? Can it be possible that it will get passed the variable in the php code.

Here is my declaration of mytext variable

```
if ($_POST['mytext']) {
    foreach ( $_POST['mytext'] as $key=>$value ) {
    $values = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value);
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO tblalumni_past_o (pastoccu, alum_id) VALUES ('$values', '$id')");
        }
    }
```

So can it get passed if the input  field mytext is not in the form?

Comment: You should check with isset or array_key_exists to avoid "undefined index", if you really want to ignore those notices (not recommended) you could specify error_level as warning, or use @ operator in front of the variable

Comment: @DanIonescu Thank you for understanding my question. ! Thanks

Comment: You're wellcome, i've also posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid "undefined index" notices the right way  you can use one of the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['mytext'])) {
    // your code
}
```

or

```
if (array_key_exists('mytext', $_POST)) {
    // your code
}
```

You could also choose to ignore them using the @ operator or by setting error_reporting above notice but that is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

**Just change you condition** `if(isset($_POST['mytext']) && is_array($_POST['mytext']))`

Comment: what? I will replace the same?

Answer (score 0):

**Replace** `if( isset($_POST['mytext']) && is_array($_POST['mytext']) )` **with** `if ($_POST['mytext'])`

Comment: what? you are like chauhan! maybe the other way around?